# How to make author names bold and make authors name and year in italic in-text citation, natbib apalike

Tags: natbib, apa-style

I want to make

1. the authors name and year in the reference list BOLD
   example:

**Beasley A, Mason W. 2015.** Emotional states vs. emotional words in social media. In:
Proceedings of the ACM web science conference. 1–10.

2. the authors names and year in italic in intext citation, example:

The online perception reconstructed by forma mentis networks indicates that pay gaps are closely semantically related to both ‘‘gender’’ and ‘‘gap’’, thus indicating that closing the gender pay gap is key for fighting gender biases in STEM, in agreement with previous relevant studies (*Ely, Ibarra & Kolb, 2011; Courey & Heywood, 2018*). (used \citep here)

*Leder, Steinbock & Martini (2009)* take into consideration structural changes of
metamorphic malware. (used \cite here)

Where should make changes in the apalike-1.bst to get like the above examples?

My `{format.names}` function looks like this :

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{ f{}}" format.name$ 't :=   % last name first
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "" * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " \textit{et~al.}" * }
                { ", " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the four desired changes you've mentioned in your posting (make authors' names bold in formatted bib items; make `year` field bold in formatted bib items; render authors' surnames in italics in the citation call-outs; and render year in italics in the citation call-outs), I've spotted at least six [6!] additional changes you appear to require relative to `apalike`'s default settings:

- Use `,` (comma) rather than the word `and` as the separator between authors in the formatted entries,
- Don't place a comma between an author's surname and (truncated) given name(s).
- Don't insert a `.` ("period", "full stop") after authors' truncated first name(s).
- Don't place parentheses around the 'year' block in the formatted entries,
- Insert `:` (colon) after the word "In" in the `booktitle` field of entries of type `@incollection` -- and maybe other entry types as well.
- Do *not* render the contents of the `booktitle` field in italics.

With enough time and resources, I believe that it should be possible -- though not particularly advisable -- to achieve all of these formatting objectives by hacking `apalike.bst`.

Before embarking on such a journey, though, you should remind yourself of the fact that `apalike` is *really old* -- it was last updated meaningfully in 1988. Its advanced age -- my apologies if this sounds needlessly [ageist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ageism)... -- entails (at least) three drawbacks, typographically speaking:

- `apalike` doesn't know about fields such as `url`, `doi`, `isbn`, and `issn`, which are rather commonplace these days.
- `apalike` doesn't work all that well with the `natbib` citation management package. E.g., `natbib`'s `longnamesfirst` option does *not* work with `apalike`.
- The `apalike` bibliography style comes *nowhere close* to implementing *current* APA formatting guidelines. This non-adherence to current APA guidelines may or may not be a drawback in practice for you. However, you should at least be aware of this issue.

In view of these drawbacks and of the fact that hacking `apalike` might be rather tricky to pull off correctly, I believe you'd be better off learning how to use the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package. The `makebst` utility lets users create a bespoke bibliography style file that implement all of their formatting requirements from the beginning, and in a very robust manner. The `makebst` utility takes you through a long sequence of questions, each with multiple-choice answers (one of which will be marked as the default). The final question will be whether you want the utility to create the bst file; do answer "y" to that question.

To get going, open a command window and type `pdflatex makebst`.